# Mix two strings in Java

Tags: java, string

I was wondering if it possible to mix two strings in java.
Suppose I have

```
11111
```

and

```
22222
```

What would be the best way to combine them to form?

```
1212121212
```

Comment: This doesn't relate to regex, so I removed the tag.

Comment: if this is homework please tag it as such

Comment: -1 (No existing approach/attempt shown on homework.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming both strings are of equal length, you could simply write a loop to go over the characters and do what you want:

```
String s1, s2; /* input strings */

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
  sb.append(s1.charAt(i));
  sb.append(s2.charAt(i));
}

String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation that preserves the remainder of unequal length strings:

```
public static String mix(String a, String b) {
    final int aLength = a.length();
    final int bLength = b.length();
    final int min = Math.min(aLength, bLength);
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(aLength + bLength);
    for(int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
        sb.append(a.charAt(i));
        sb.append(b.charAt(i));
    }
    if (aLength > bLength) {
        sb.append(a, bLength, aLength);
    } else if (aLength < bLength) {
        sb.append(b, aLength, bLength);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - iterate the first string, and for each char in it, append to a builder the char in the same position from the second string (if it exists):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
    sb.append(str1.charAt(i));
    if (str.length() > i) {
       sb.append(str2.charAt(i));
    }   
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the example given is intentional, i.e they all have 1 char repeated. In that case it is much simpler. If they are not, then other answers are good.

Comment: No it should work when any string of the same length, and it shouldn't matter if the chars are repeated or not.